# Передача данных между python и node.js

Tags: python, node.js, python-2.x

Здравствуй, есть скрипт на Python, который получает данные от датчиков и управляет моторами (это не важно) и node.js ,который работает с клиентом через [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Как можно передать данные из python скрипта в js скрипт и наоборот?

Пробовал запускать python из под node.js, через библиотеку [python-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell)
Но данные от python скрипта доходят только после его завершения, а мне нужно передавать данные во время работы скрипта.

Comment: А python скрипт работает как демон? Или запускается время от времени?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, как демон.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это типичная проблема сопряжения разнородных систем (не только python + node.js).

В зависимости от специфики задачи, для передачи данных между подсистемами могут использоваться потоки ввода-вывода, socket-соединения, разделяемая память, различные IPC решения и множество других методов.

В общем случае, когда подсистемы находятся на разных машинах (физических или виртуальных), задача может быть решена через использование *посредника* для передачи сообщений из одной подсистемы в другую. Хорошим (хотя и несколько избыточным) решением может быть очередь сообщений: ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ и т.д. Можно попробовать использовать Redis, с его [реализацией Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

Если говорить о вашем конкретном случае, то можно попробовать реализовать клиент socket.io в python приложении, и отправлять данные по этому каналу. Мне кажется, это будет одним из самых простых и нетребовательных к ресурсам решений.

Comment: посредник не обязателен. Можно использовать: pipes, sockets, shared memory, или любой другой IPC method, который работает для двух процессов на одной машине.

Comment: Если рассматривать задачу в наиболее общей постановке, то речь должна идти о _разных машинах_. Как следствие, из приведенных вами вариантов остаются только socket соединения. Использование других типов взаимодействия существенно зависит от специфики задачи.

Comment: в любом случае, прежде чем устанавливать RabbitMQ итд, нужно рассмотреть более простые методы.

Comment: Разумеется. Именно поэтому я написал в ответе, что решение с очередью несколько избыточно и предложил использовать  socket.io в данном конкретном случае :)

Comment: переписывание одного из процессов на другом языке не является более простым методом. Хотя в среднесрочной перспективе, это тоже может быть вариантом со своим набором достоинств и недостатков.

Comment: Переписывание процесса на другом языке в корне меняет постановку задачи. А текущей постановке задача довольно часто встречается на практике (я не говорю именно о связке node.js + python). А очередь является одним из наиболее простых и гибких решений задачи в общей постановке.

Comment: @jfs, обновил ответ.